# Overload dropdownmenu - no function at the second option

Tags: laravel

Having two dropdown menus which has dropdown options: days and times, for example Days: Monday,Wednesday,Saturday and times: 08:00-10:00. It gets confusing cause days option apears the times options and the times option nothing.

Index.blade.php:

```
@section('title')
    Shopping Cart
@endsection
@section('content')    
    @foreach($products->chunk(3) as $productsChunk)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($productsChunk as $products)
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="{{ $products->imagePath }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>{{ $products->title }}</h3>
                            <p class="description">{{ $products->description }}</p>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                <div class="container">
                                <h2>Laravel Dependent</h2>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="day">Select Day:</label>
                                            <select name1="day" class="form-control" style="width:250px">
                                                <option value="">--- Select Day ---</option>
                                                @foreach ($days as $key => $value)
                                                <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="time">Select Time:</label>
                                            <select name1="time" class="form-control"style="width:150px">
                                            <option>--Time--</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                jQuery(document).ready(function ()
                                {
                                        jQuery('select[name1="day"]').on('change',function(){
                                        var dayID = jQuery(this).val();
                                        if(dayID)
                                        {
                                            jQuery.ajax({
                                                url : 'shop.index/getindex/' +dayId,
                                                type : "GET",
                                                dataType : "json",
                                                success:function(data)
                                                {
                                                    console.log(data);
                                                    jQuery('select[name1="day"]').empty();
                                                    jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                                                    $('select[name1="day"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            $('select[name1="day"]').empty();
                                        }
                                        });
                                });
                                </script> 
                                <div class="container">                            
                             <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="days">Select Day:</label>
                            <select name1="day" class="form-control" style="width:250px">
                                <option value="">--- Select Day ---</option>
                                @foreach ($days as $key => $value)
                                <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="time">Select Time:</label>
                            <select name2="time" class="form-control"style="width:250px">
                            <option>--Time--</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                          </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            jQuery(document).ready(function ()
                            {
                                    jQuery('select[name2="time"]').on('change',function(){
                                    var timesID = jQuery(this).val();
                                    if(timesID)
                                    {
                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                            url : 'index/getindex/' +timesID,
                                            type : "GET",
                                            dataType : "json",
                                            success:function(data)
                                            {
                                                console.log(data);
                                                jQuery('select[name2="time"]').empty();
                                                jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                                                $('select[name2="time"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $('select[name2="time"]').empty();
                                    }
                                    });
                            });
                </script>                  
                                <div class="pull-left price">${{ $products->price }}</div>
                                <a href="{{ route('product.addToCart', ['id' => $products->id]) }}"
                                   class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">Add to cart</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

ProductController.php:

```
public function getIndex() { 
        $products = Product::all();
        $days = Day::all();
        $times = Time::all();
        $days = DB::table('days')->pluck("name1","id");
        $times = DB::table('times')->pluck("name2","id");
        return view('shop.index',compact('days','times','products')); 
        
        }
```

The meaning of the specific issue is:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check your `HTML`, you're mixing `JavaScript` with `HTML` (here `<script type="text/javascript"> <div class="container"> ...`).

Comment: You mean that <div class="container"> must be after type="text/javascript">?

Comment: Learn more about [`script`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tags on MDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the index.blade.php with option at times:

```
<label for="time">Select Time:</label>
                                                <select name2="time" class="form-control"style="width:250px">
                                                <option value="">--Time--</option>
                                                @foreach ($times as $key => $value)
                                                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
```